# PHP Session storing behavior into variables?

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, session-variables

*this is only happening in Chrome*

Has anyone ever experienced PHP sessions storing functional behavior into variables? I created the following script:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['count'] = (isset($_SESSION['count'])) ? $_SESSION['count'] + 1 : 0;

   echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

You'd think this would echo 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. on each page load. However, I'm getting 1, 3, 5, 7, and so on. I found out that for some reason, $_SESSION['count'] acts as though its incrementing behavior has been stored within the variable. The reason it seems to increase by two on each page load is because when $_SESSION['count'] is called, it's automatically increasing by one. To make it clear, the following script will output and higher number on each page load.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

This will echo whatever $_SESSION['count'] was and then $_SESSION['count'] + 1 for every page load. I've tried unsetting the session, clearing the $_SESSION variables, and creating new files in various directories with the same script. I also tried it on http://codepad.viper-7.com/, and it works correctly. Anyone have an idea as to why this would happen? I've experienced similar behavior today when setting a session variable to a random number. On each page load, I get a new random number simply by echoing the variable. When I serialize or var_dump the variable, it simply gives back a string value.

This is what I used to unset the session:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

I've tried the script on several browsers. IE and Firefox correctly increment by 1; however Chrome increments by 2. Any idea why the browser could influence this?

EDIT: If I create a new script and change the variable, it works correctly. What I've noticed is that whenever I require this script from index.php, such that index.php simply has , I begin to have this problem again. So, something's going on with index.php. Could there be an issue with my .htaccess loading the page more than once? Here it is:

My .htaccess
    Options +FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

DirectoryIndex /index.php
FallbackResource /index.php

#Allow cross domain AJAX
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

EDIT AGAIN: Per user2086860's request in the comments, I'm going to run through the complete code flow.

First, I create a script with the following code:

```
 <?php
     session_start();

     $_SESSION['counter'] = (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) ? $_SESSION['counter'] + 1 : 0;

     echo $_SESSION['counter'];

 ?>
```

This code on its own works as expected, printing 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Now, if I require this script via my index.php like so:

```
<?php
    require 'test6.php';
?>
```

The numbers begin to increase by 2 rather than 1. It is this requiring via my index.php that causes the problem. It also screws up my script file, such that accessing test6.php directly now increases by 2 instead of 1. You can see it in action here:

***test URL removed***

Just so I'm clear, the above code is ***all of my code***. There is nothing else included in index.php or test6.php. This is only happening in Chrome. Firefox and Internet Explorer are working correctly, incrementing by 1.

Comment: How are you clearing the session?  are you sure you cleared it? using unset() or session_destroy()

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling or including the script twice?

Comment: I tried your exact code on http://codepad.viper-7.com/wsm3re and it outputs 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: There is no "reference" behavior occurring here nor is there "[a] behavior [that] has been stored within the variable". Thus the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I'm with @HeikkiU, you must have some other code adding to the count

Comment: @fedmich I've edited the question, including what I used to unset the session.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the scripting isn't getting called twice, however this wouldn't explain why the variable would increase by 1 without any incrementing function, as seen in the lower script.

Comment: Updated the question with my .htaccess to see if there's an issue there.

Comment: Don't you have any browser extensions that may double your requests?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller no, I don't.

Comment: As you have defined `FallbackResource` in your htacess, check network tab on chrome debugger to see if it is not trying to get some non-existing images/stylesheets or even favicons and running index.php instead.

Comment: I am getting 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 .... and so on on my wamp server.Please paste you complete code associated with it i.e. server side, client side, etc.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I checked the network tab, and it's only getting the domain url. You can check it out here: https://mystronyx.com/

Comment: @user2981164 Also check server access logs - request for favicon.ico is not registered on network tab, and all modern browsers asks for it automatically. Also on other browsers it starts from 0 but next is 2 and then it increments by one - they can tak whatever delivered as favicon and be happy with it, but for chrome it is corrupted image so it tries getting it after each request.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller thanks, you're probably on the right track. I added a line to the script to add the word 'test' to a file, and in chrome it's adding it to the file twice, whereas IE and FireFox add it once. So, that means the code is definitely being run twice in Chrome. I'll check out favicon.ico.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, adding a favicon to my page fixed the problem. Chrome is now incrementing by 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome (and apparently other browsers) was looking for a favicon, or the image that appears next to the page title. As soon as I added a stock image to my page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" 
  type="image/png" 
  href="https://mysite.com/icon.png">
</head>
```

It worked. Thanks to @dev-null-dweller for suggesting this!

Comment: Don't just add the favicon image. You have to fix your htaccess too. This just mean your htaccess hogs all of your traffic and runs index.php for any 404 requests.

Comment: Maybe move your counter code out of index.php and into other php file. but again this depends on the main logic of your app...

Comment: @fedmich, sorry, I'm not clear. What needs changing in the .htaccess?

Comment: Sometimes some crawler will scan robots.txt on the root. that means it will make your counter function run again if its in index.php, there are a lot more "patterns" that is possible. so your htaccess must not hog all 404 requests.