# Google Chrome: PHP code would be executed twice when session was started

Tags: php, variables, session, double, runtime

I need to set a dynamic id for every document load. This ID should be set in PHP. Now, when i set a `session_start()`, the php code would be executed twice because the ID-code in generated document source differs from the same code in the alerted script variable. There are no runtime errors.

What's wrong with this code and how can i prevent the session to re-execute my code after `session_start()` ?

And when the code would be executed twice (var idvar contains a different value) why the heck is alert executed only once?

I simplified the script so you can try for your self:

```
<?php

// Session start generates two different ID's
session_start();

// Create ID
$time = microtime(1);
$parts = explode('.', (string)$time);
$idvar = strtoupper(strrev(dechex($parts[0]) . dechex($parts[1]))) . dechex(rand());

?>

<script>
    // Contains a new generated ID after session_start()
    var IDvr = '<?php print $idvr; ?>';
    alert(IDvr);
</script>
```

Screenshots:

[image: Alert dialog]
[image: Browser Source (Chrome) of the same page!]

Comment: Here you are generating an HTML page, including a JS alert, containing the id generated with the HTML. What is the problem with this id. How do you see it runs twice ? have any logs ? You see it on user action ? This code looks to be run on every page refresh/submit...

Comment: How to see: Execute the script and look at the alerted code. Now look at the generated html code. The code in IDvr and alert is now different.

Comment: You must miss something... the alert message can't be different from what `IDvr` shows... By the way, you should alert the content of `IDvr` instead of the php code. There is no reason for the server to send it twice, except if this is not the full executed code... Sorry but I can't try it myself...

Comment: Its to fly off the handle. I even don't understand this, but the code differs even when i put IDvr in alert. The code with js runtime is different from the html generated. I hope anyone is able to reproduce this.

Comment: Update: Thanks to Tezla we identified that the difference only occours in chrome. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Can't see how a browser could generate this behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Try move the id initialization just before `session_start()` i suspect it related on how things executed in php after `session_start()`.

**Edit**
still unable to reproduce it
[image]

Comment: Thank you, i tryed this already. Same behavior. Can you try the code above?

Comment: well, after i fiddled with your code i can't reproduce your case. Indeed session_start() in either position did affect nothing. Although i saw idvar and idvr and i asume it's idvar.

Comment: Thank you. Can you send your fiddle?

Comment: I don't find a online processor to execute this code. You must try this on a server.

Comment: i tested your code on my xampp and lamp (ubuntu). What is your php version? And also, browser to test the code. I am using Firefox Developer.

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought about a browser issue before. I tryed it in IE and Firefox. Works as expected. The problem occours only in Chrome 46.0.xxxx. Therefore i think the PHP version is irellevant.

Comment: well, maybe you should file a bug report if nobody reported it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

[PHP Session storing behavior into variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918256/php-session-storing-behavior-into-variables)
But even when i add a favicon to the page it don't works. Also the page is standalone and not included as require in another page.

Even this is not working!

```
// Session start generates two different ID's
if(!isset($_SESSION) && !isset($idvr)) {
    session_start();
    // Create ID
    $time = microtime(1);
    $parts = explode('.', (string)$time);
    $idvr  = strtoupper(strrev(dechex($parts[0]) . dechex($parts[1]))) . dechex(rand());
}
```

Update:

Now corrected:

With view-source:pgname and session initialized the code would be executed again in source view!